# HighChart Stacked chart overlapping smaller data size

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm using Jugal's workspace editor, 
     http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/bgNBG/
In JS section I applied my own JS and facing one issue.

Large amount of data will overlapped whole data points. Can anyone help in that ?

```js
var chartingOptions = {
 chart : {
  type : "bar",
    renderTo : 'container',
  inverted : true
 },
 title : {
  text : "Bunny Chart"
 },
 xAxis : {
  title : {
   text : ""
  },
  type : "category",
  categories : ["DIP", "C", "Can", "Sch", "DC"]
 },
 yAxis : {
  title : {
   text : ""
  },
  min : 0.0,
  max : 503.0
 },
 column : {
  stacking : "normal"
 },
 legend : {
  enabled : true,
  align : "center",
  floating : false,
  itemMarginBottom : 0,
  itemMarginTop : 0,
  layout : "horizontal",
  lineHeight : 0,
  verticalAlign : "bottom",
  x : 0,
  y : 0
 },
 credits : {
  enabled : false
 },
 plotOptions : {
  area : {},
  bar : {},
  pie : {
   dataLabels : {}
  },
  series : {
   cursor : 'pointer',
  // stacking : 'normal',
   point : {
    events : {
     click : {}
    }
   }
  },
  column: {
   grouping: false,
   shadow: false
  }
 },
 series : [{
   data : [{
     y : 74.0,
     name : "A",
     color : "#CCFF90",
     ddlRecordIds : [243496, 243496, 243501, 243501, 243506, 243506],
     
    }, {
     y : 2.0,
     name : "A",
     color : "#CCFF90",
     ddlRecordIds : [243641, 243641, 243676, 243676]
    }
   ],
   name : "A",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#CCFF90"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 28.0,
     name : "B",
     color : "#FFFF90",
     ddlRecordIds : [243881, 243881, 243886, 243886]
    }, {
     y : 3.0,
     name : "B",
     color : "#FFFF90",
     ddlRecordIds : [243926, 243926, 243961, 243961, 243981, 243981]
    }
   ],
   name : "B",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#FFFF90"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 25.0,
     name : "C",
     color : "#FFCCFF",
     ddlRecordIds : [244726, 244726, 244731, 244731]
    }
   ],
   name : "C",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#FFCCFF"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 62.0,
     name : "E",
     color : "#CC6699",
     ddlRecordIds : [244036, 244036, 244041, 244041]
    }, {
     y : 2.0,
     name : "E",
     color : "#CC6699",
     ddlRecordIds : [244211, 244211, 244296, 244296]
    }
   ],
   name : "E",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#CC6699"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 8.0,
     name : "F",
     color : "#FF3300",
     ddlRecordIds : [244851, 244851, 244856, 244856]
    }
   ],
   name : "F",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#FF3300"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 174.0,
     name : "G",
     color : "#6666CC",
     ddlRecordIds : [244891, 244891, 244896, 244896]
    }
   ],
   name : "G",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#6666CC"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 85.0,
     name : "H",
     color : "#666666",
     ddlRecordIds : [245761, 245761, 245766, 245766]
    }
   ],
   name : "H",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#666666"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 161.0,
     name : "I",
     color : "#669999",
     ddlRecordIds : [234731, 234731, 234751, 234751]
    }, {
     y : 503.0,
     name : "I",
     color : "#669999",
     ddlRecordIds : [234736, 234736, 234741, 234741]
    }, {
     y : 355.0,
     name : "I",
     color : "#669999",
     ddlRecordIds : [234771, 234771, 234776, 234776]
    }, {
     y : 35.0,
     name : "I",
     color : "#669999",
     ddlRecordIds : [234936, 234936, 235186, 235186]
    }
   ],
   name : "I",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#669999"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 232.0,
     name : "J",
     color : "#009999",
     ddlRecordIds : [237406, 237406, 237411, 237411]
    }, {
     y : 20.0,
     name : "J",
     color : "#009999",
     ddlRecordIds : [237466, 237466, 237471, 237471]
    }
   ],
   name : "J",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#009999"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 61.0,
     name : "K",
     color : "#CCFF99",
     ddlRecordIds : [244416, 244416, 244421, 244421]
    }, {
     y : 1.0,
     name : "K",
     color : "#CCFF99",
     ddlRecordIds : [244441, 244441]
    }
   ],
   name : "K",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#CCFF99"
  }, {
   data : [{
     y : 460.0,
     name : "L",
     color : "#FFFF99",
     ddlRecordIds : [241196, 241196, 241201, 241201]
    }
   ],
   name : "L",
   grouping : false,
   pointPadding: 0.1,
   dataLabels : {
    enabled : true
   },
   color : "#FFFF99"
  }
 ],
 dataGrouping : {
  groupPixelWidth : 40
 }
};

chartingOptions = $.extend({}, jugalsLib.getBasicChartOptions(), chartingOptions);
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartingOptions);
```

Comment: Please fix the snippet errors! Currently i get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" when I try to run it.

Comment: @Botimoo : may you please use http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/bgNBG/ URL for testing. just copy and paste snippet in JS section. you can find the issus

Comment: You have series.grouping set to false - this is causing your issue. Instead of grouping: false you should be able to use stacking: http://jsfiddle.net/bgNBG/59/